# Use more than 3 GB of memory on SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise x64

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am running SQL Server 2005 Standard x64 on Windows server 2003 R2 x64. I have 32GB of total server RAM. I am unable to make SQL Server use more than 3 GB of memory, even I set min and max server options as follows:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure 'min server memory', 1024
RECONFIGURE
go

sp_configure 'max server memory', 24576
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

What could be a problem?

**Update**

There was SQL Server 2005 32bit installed. See my answer.

Comment: How big is your dataset? SQL will only use what it needs to so if your dataset is less than 3GB then it's wont user more than that

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did recognize that there was 32 bit version of SQL server installed. After re-installation the problem was solved.

Thank you very much for your efforts.

Cheers
Darius

Answer (score -3):

You need to add a directive to the Boot.ini on your root drive.

under the 
[operating systems] header
you should add /3gb  switch at the end of the OS entry.

Comment: Doesn't apply to 64-bit operating systems

Comment: You don't need this on 64bit systems, it's a workaround for limitations on 32bit systems